# How to install the specific version of postgresql?

Tags: 14.04, postgresql

I need to install a postgresql **9.6.6** on Ubuntu 14.04, but the command

```
apt-get install postgresql-9.6
```

installes 9.6.7.

How can I install 9.6.6?

An output of command

```
apt-cache policy postgresql-9.6
```

is

```
  Installed: 9.6.7-1.pgdg14.04+1
  Candidate: 9.6.7-1.pgdg14.04+1
  Version table:
 *** 9.6.7-1.pgdg14.04+1 0
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/statusPackages
            100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

Comment: Older versions are archived on launchpad.net (LP). Note that LP is not a repository; you must manually download all the packages and dependencies from LP, then install using dpkg (not apt).

Comment: Thank you! Could you explain it in detail?

Comment: You are attempting to do an unsupported action (downgrading). You can do it --it's your system-- but you won't find much technical support for it here. It requires three skills: Navigating Launchpad.net, installing packages using dpkg, and resolving package dependencies manually (using dpkg instead of apt). Those skills must be *learned*; there are no detailed step-by-step instructions. Depending upon your skill level, a good search engine might get you a long way. However, if you run into trouble, our best advice will be to install the supported version of the package.